# TSQL - Finding Row Duplicates by Grouped Time Window - without Cursor

Tags: sql-server

A certain system sends duplicate messages that match each important characteristic except the datetime. Instead, the system may send up to 50 duplicates that differ by a few seconds only; for example, the first message is sent at 07:59:41 (hhmmss) and the 50th is sent at 08:00:07 with each of the others somewhere in between. I want to treat each of these messages as the same, processing the first that has not been processed by my service and marking the others with an error code. I have chosen a two minute window within which messages will be marked equal; this is an acceptable assumption.

I have the following working logic, but the query is extremely slow for larger potential duplicate pools. For less than 10 records, it can process in just a few seconds, but for 1000 records it takes about ten minutes.

Here is the logic as implemented:
For each message check to see whether any message received both one minute before or one minute after has been processed by the service. If such case is found, set message to error code.

Questions:
 1. Is there an alternative to Cursor for this case? (I tried a while loop but it performed no better.)
 2. If not, is there something I could do improve performance? (Trying to limit the records necessary to search based on the primary key didn't have an effect on performance; I leave the attempt commented out.)

```
 --create dataset
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM rosterload.RosterFeed WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE StatusCode = 1
    AND DateDiff(MINUTE, CreatedTimeStamp, SYSDATETIME()) > 60

DECLARE @PKpotentialDuplicate AS INT;
DECLARE @PKrange INT
--SET @PKrange = 2000
DECLARE @DuplicateCursor AS CURSOR;

SET @DuplicateCursor = CURSOR
FOR

SELECT PK_RosterFeed
FROM #temp --TODO: rosterload.RosterFeed where StatusCode = 1

OPEN @DuplicateCursor;

FETCH NEXT
FROM @DuplicateCursor
INTO @PKpotentialDuplicate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            --DECLARE @PKpotentialDuplicate as INT; DECLARE @PKrange int SET @PKrange = 2000 SET @PKpotentialDuplicate = 531474
            SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM rosterload.RosterFeed WITH (NOLOCK) --rosterload.RosterFeed 
            WHERE
                --PK_RosterFeed > (select PK_RosterFeed - 2000 from rosterload.RosterFeed where PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate) and PK_RosterFeed < (select PK_RosterFeed + 2000 from rosterload.RosterFeed where PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate) and
                ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, EvtTimeStamp, (
                            SELECT EvtTimeStamp
                            FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                            WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                            ))) < 60
                AND AssigningAuthorityCode = (
                    SELECT AssigningAuthorityCode
                    FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                    WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                    )
                AND PatientIdentifier = (
                    SELECT PatientIdentifier
                    FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                    WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                    )
                AND EventType = (
                    SELECT EventType
                    FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                    WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                    )
                AND PatientClass = (
                    SELECT PatientClass
                    FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                    WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                    )
                AND MessageType = (
                    SELECT MessageType
                    FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                    WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                    )
                AND ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, EvtTimeStamp, (
                            SELECT EvtTimeStamp
                            FROM rosterload.RosterFeed
                            WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
                            ))) < 60
                AND PK_RosterFeed != @PKpotentialDuplicate
                AND StatusCode <> 1
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #temp
        SET StatusCode = 15
        WHERE PK_RosterFeed = @PKpotentialDuplicate
    END

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @DuplicateCursor
    INTO @PKpotentialDuplicate
END

CLOSE @DuplicateCursor;

DEALLOCATE @DuplicateCursor;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure you can do this using a normal set based update. The `EXISTS` clause simply checks for a similar record in the previous minute, where one is found the later records are updated:

```
UPDATE  r
SET     StatusCode = 15
FROM    rosterload.RosterFeed AS r
WHERE   r.StatusCode = 1
AND     r.CreatedTimeStamp >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, SYSDATETIME())
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    rosterload.RosterFeed AS r2
            WHERE   r2.AssigningAuthorityCode = r.AssigningAuthorityCode
            AND     r2.EventType = r.EventType
            AND     r2.PatientIdentifier = r.PatientIdentifier
            AND     r2.PatientClass = r.PatientClass
            AND     r2.MessageType = r.MessageType
            AND     r2.EvtTimeStamp < r.EvtTimeStamp
            AND     r2.EvtTimeStamp >= DATEADD(SECOND, -60, r.EvtTimeStamp)
            AND     r2.StatusCode != 1
        );
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm impressed, thank you. FYI - I changed r.CreatedTimeStamp >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, SYSDATETIME()) to r.CreatedTimeStamp < DATEADD(MINUTE, -20, SYSDATETIME()). Looking for active records as they are being inserted into the db is extremely slow; e.g., 175 rows 00:09:12. Looking for active records that haven't been picked up by the service after 20 minutes, e.g., 169 rows 00:00:01.